# how to create notificationUrl in Create subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

{
"changeType": "created",
"notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
"resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
"expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
"clientState": "secretClientValue",
"latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}

Comment: how to create notificationUrl in Create subscription

Answer (score 0):

`notificationUrl` is your own API endpoint that Graph will send the notification to. It can be any public web HTTPS interface with a certificate issued by a Known CA. I suggest you check [Use Change Notifications and Track Changes with Microsoft Graph Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/) where [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is used to expose an endpoint running on your local machine to accept MS Graph change notifications